# Django-based Docker project will connect to local postgres DB on windows machines but not on a Mac or Linux machine

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

Been struggling with this issue for close to a month now and I am at my wits end.

I have the following docker-compose.yml file:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    container_name: targeting
    build: ./Targeting
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/project/
    ports:
      - "80:80"

  db:
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    restart: always
    image: postgres
    container_name: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${NAME}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_PORT=${PORT}
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    container_name: pgadmin4_container
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8888:80"
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: user-name@domain-name.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: strong-password
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:/var/lib/pgadmin

volumes:
  postgres_data:
  pgadmin-data:
```

and I have the following .env file:

```
SECRET_KEY=random_secret_key
DEBUG=TRUE

NAME=postgres
USER=postgres
PASSWORD=password
HOST=db
PORT=5432
```

The following Dockerfile is used to create the python container:

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.11.4-slim-buster

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/project

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ../requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copy project
COPY .. .
```

On a Windows machine, after a docker *compose build* and a *docker compose up* command is issued, the project will be up and running and the django project will connect to the postgres database perfectly fine. I have verified this on two Windows machines. However, on mac or linux, I get a "*connection failed: FATAL: password authentication failed for the user "postgres*" error and I have no idea why.

my settings.py file for Django looks like this. I use Python decouple to use .env variables.

```py
from decouple import config

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql",
        "NAME": config('NAME'),
        "USER": config('USER'),
        "PASSWORD": config('PASSWORD'),
        "HOST": config('HOST'),
        "PORT": config('PORT')
    }
}
```

Anyone have any suggestions? I am guessing it could be something to do with paths, but I have not been able to find out the solution. Thanks.

I have tried credentials for a postgres database on a RDS instance in the env file and that worked fine on the Mac and linux machines.

Comment: Generally *"connection failed: FATAL: password authentication failed for the user "postgres"* means either the password value is incorrect or the password type is incorrect. For recent Postgres versions password type issues means mixing `md5` and `scram256` passwords. You should look at what the `pg_hba.conf` has set for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this before if I made changes to the Postgres credentials *and re-used the same volume*. The Postgres volume will persist the initial `POSTGRES_USER` and `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` values from the first time compose was used to create the containers. I had changed one or both of those values, but didn't destroy the old Postgres volume, and I would get similar user/password errors to your issue when Django tried to connect.

I run on WSL2 and my compose file looks similar to yours. I don't think you're missing anything platform-specific.

I would test a fresh anonymous volume for your `postgres` service and see if it accepts the given credentials. I would also try to get into a PgAdmin shell and connect to the DB container with the credentials used by Django.